# Executing a javascript that is injected as a script element via bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, bookmarklet

I am using bookmarklet to inject a  element in document with a custom JS script file. I did it like this:

```
var newscript = document.createElement('script');
newscript.type = 'text/javascript';
newscript.async = true;
newscript.src = 'http://www.myurl.com/my_js_script.js';
var oldscript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
oldscript.parentNode.insertBefore(newscript, oldscript);
```

But I can't figure out how to actually execute it. Can someone tell me how can I execute that JS file?

*Note*: Since this can be a Greasemonkey script as well, I am tagging this question for Greasemonkey as well.

Comment: Your `src` attribute is set with a repeated protocol, but otherwise, your script should run as you had added it to the document.

Comment: That was a copy paste mistake, actually there is going otbe only one protocol (not repeated). Thanks for pointing though.

Comment: If that was a copy-paste mistake, **edit the question to fix it**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Script tags are automatically downloaded and executed when they're added to the document. Note, however, that the script you're using may fail if the document you're injecting into doesn't already contain any `<script>` tags, as `oldscript` will be undefined.

Comment: I didn't know that. If that is the case, then this is the right answer. I will confirm it and accept in a couple of days. _(or unless you could point me to some url that says something like that, then I will accept it right away)_.